# Change color of output text in Netbeans IDE window and clear the output area

Tags: java, netbeans, window

Okay, I'm only in chapter 3 of my Java book, and I'm wanting to do something that would help with reading the output window of my Netbeans 8.0.2 IDE. I want this so I can change the color of outputs that are answers or results of something that my program is creating.

As far as I know, what you can do is only client-side and if you try to transfer the program itself to a new computer, it will not change the color of text. What I am looking for is some line(s) of code that can declare a color to a letter or line of characters.

Something around the likes of: 
System.out.println.colorRED;

And when this line of code is hit in the program, instead of the IDE showing black (default color) in the output window, it displays it as the color Red, or #ff0000.

[Arrows are what I want to be Red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WbiBK.jpg)

I am also looking for something else that would be very helpful in terms of clearing up the window where the IDE outputs System.out.println to. I would like a "cls" of sorts, and any includes that would be needed for said code to work. I don't want a simulated window clear, I want a legitimate clear like C++ has. It's okay if it's OS dependent. (I want this so that I can remove the tons of output spam whenever the user is looping through my program)

As you can see in the picture above, it has 2+ runs of the program and will soon start using the slider to go to the next operation. I want it so before it prints out the output, that it clears that window, and starts over as if the program was stopped and re-ran (Text appearing at the top instead of the simulated cls, at the bottom).

Thanks to anyone who can help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If the console supports ANSI coloring, you can use special ANSI characters to define colors**.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code

```
public static final String ANSI_RESET = "\u001B[0m";
public static final String ANSI_RED = "\u001B[31m";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(ANSI_RED + "This text is red!" + ANSI_RESET);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! and the fact that you can change the name of the string values is equally amazing! :D